# How a modern day coup would unfold?

Tags: government, politics, cyberpunk

Imagine the **steps** necessary to initiate a modern-day political regime change (democratic to autocratic).

What would come first and **how would it build up** to the complete shift of power?

Think cybersecurity, unique weak points in a society, conflicting ideologies...
Ideologies could involve technology, religion, spirituality, prejudices, environment, class struggle and/or a mix of all these.

Comment: Have you been watching US news in the past couple of months? /s

Comment: This feels like a question for Politics.SE rather than here.

Comment: Where is the worldbuilding? Where is the research too?

Comment: [*A Very British Coup*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Very_British_Coup_(TV_series)) (1988), British mini-series. [*Secret State*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secret_State_(TV_series)) (2012), British mini-series.

Comment: Reference: USA 2021(failed miserably). Also reference Myanmar 2021(Succeeded). Also reference Haiti 2021(failed). You might want to peruse https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_coups_and_coup_attempts . Any *real* answer would run to hundreds or thousands of pages of text.

Answer (score 4):

#### "The election was stolen!" - Look at USA and Myanmar

There are two really good examples of this in the news right now. The USA coup attempt shows really good examples of how to indoctrinate and build distrust in opponents over time and some popular support for the coup, the Myanmar coup shows clearly how to follow through with it using the military.

Had the USA coup had military support (and it really could of as Trump made military appointments in his presidency), the Capitol raid could've "succeded" with pence hanging from a noose, trump claiming victory and nobody brave enough to stand up to him.

Had the Myanmar coup had 49% of the voting public protesting with the insurectionists and chanting "stop the steal" and beating pro-democracy protesters, the conflict would find it's way into most households divide and conquer, and thus the general strike by the population would be much more manageable, or non existent.

So, copy paste every news story in the USA until Nov 2020, add more of trump booting out and replacing all the generals with his own supporters, and then every Myanmar news story from then on.

Realistically both will lead to international condemnations, sanctions, recession, starvation, and eventually another coup.

Answer (score 1):

**Nazi Germany is a fine example.**

1. Gain popular support for your party.
2. Win seats in the democratically elected bodies for your party.
3. Manufacture a crisis justifying curtailment of liberties.  Curtail them through official action of the democratically elected body.  For the Nazis this was the [Reichstag fire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reichstag_fire). Use this curtailment against the enemies of your party.
4. Use circumstances to justify removal of power from democratically elected bodies - for the Nazis this was [The Enabling Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enabling_Act_of_1933).

I may not have understood those middle movies completely but I think something of the sort happened in the Star Wars universe.  Clones may have been involved.

I think a key thing for doing it this way is that a large portion of the populace is not that keen on keeping democracy for the sake of democracy.
and supports you and what you stand for.  This tricky last piece is why I think I have not been able to parlay my "Groupies and CheezIts for Willk" platform into my own autocratic rule.

Comment: You missed the street battles against the communists, and part of the political middle ground deciding that they'd rather back the genocidal nazis than the revolutionary communists. Also, arresting opposition MPs before the vote makes sure that the dictator does have an impressive majority.

Comment: "Willkes Reich" and "Heil Willk!" do sound catchy ^.^